# Executing the windows batch file

Tags: shell, unix, batch-file, plink, pscp

**What I am doing currently-**

1. Execute the shell script on `MachineB` from `MachineA` (Windows Environment).
2. Then wait for the shell script to complete its task, in my case it will write the output to a text file.
3. And after the shell script has completed all its task means it finished writing everything to a txt file, then copy that txt file to `MachineA` (Windows Environment) from `MachineB`.

So for this I wrote a `Windows Batch file` that will do the above task and it is working fine for me. Below is the Windows Bat file that I am using currently.

```
plink uname@machineB -m email.sh 
pscp  uname@machineB:/export/home/uname/jk_attachment22.txt C:\PLINK\foo.txt
```

But by using the above windows batch file, I need to type password two times which is pain, Firstly I need to type for the first line and then again for the second line.

**My Question is-**

So Is there any way I can run the above windows batch file by just typing `password` once at the command prompt. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

This is what I have when I was looking for `/.ssh folder`.

**Update:**

```
bash-3.00$ cd ~/.ssh
bash-3.00$ pwd
/home/uname/.ssh
bash-3.00$ ls -lt
total 2
-rw-r--r--   1 uname   gid-uname     489 Jul 26 18:55 known_hosts
```

So I need to make some other changes here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the password and auth with ssh key.
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152

Comment: How can I do this considering my above scenario as I tried reading the whole article and I got more confused. Any suggestion what changes I need to make? As I am running PLINK from my windows machine. So all the changes I need to make will be on my windows machine or Unix Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use the -pw option in your command line utilities.

Let's say you name your batch file TWINKIE.BAT.  At the command prompt, you'd type "TWINKIE password", where "password" is the actual password you want to use.

```
C:\>twinkie password
```

The "password" is passed into your batch file as the first command line variable, %1. Your batch file would be:

```
plink -pw %1 uname@machineB -m email.sh
pscp  -pw %1 uname@machineB:/export/home/uname/jk_attachment22.txt C:\PLINK\foo.txt
```